# typescript: совокупность типов

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

подскажите пожалуйста можно ли в typescript дать имя совокупности типов, чтобы не таскать портянку по типу

```
data : Array<ICustomSelectData> | (() => Array<ICustomSelectData>)
```

а делать так:

```
data : my_data_t
```

и где-то указать что-то на подобии

```
using my_data_t = Array<ICustomSelectData> | (() => Array<ICustomSelectData>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type my_data_type = Array<ICustomSelectData> | (() => Array<ICustomSelectData>);
let data: my_data_type;
```